# Expect script for copying file

Tags: linux, shell, expect

I am trying to copy all files but using expect command

I have the following script with expect.dat file

I have the following error, what am I doing wrong or how do I have to build the command to copy the files

command

expect expect.dat

File expect.dat

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set src_file "/process/source"
set dest_file "/process/destination"

# Run the cp command and wait for the response
spawn cp -r $src_file $dest_file
expect "*?(y/n)?"
send "y\r"
expect eof
```

Error

```
spawn cp -r /process/source /process/destination
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "y\r""
    (file "expect.dat" line 8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"spawn id not open" means the `cp` command has already exited so there's no process to `send` something to.

If the `cp` command *might* ask you a question, you'll want to `expect` *either* the pattern *or* eof

```
expect {
  "*?(y/n)?" {send "y\r"; exp_continue}
  eof
}
```

Are you sure you need [expect](/questions/tagged/expect) for this at all?

```bash
cp -r -f /process/source /process/destination
```